# how to Login with auth and authorized mvc using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

How can I `login` in mvc?

I'm a newbie in `mvc`.

I have an advance knowledge in `c#`.

Can anyone teach me how to login with `authentication` and it must be `authorized`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Roles and ActionFilter

[Refer](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs)